# How can I select tkinter entry widget with binded key?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanna select specific tkinter entry widget with binded key.

```
from tkinter import *

def select_e1(event):
    # Select E1 Entry for starting typing


def select_e2(event):
    # Select E2 Entry for starting typing

top = Tk()
top.geometry("300x200")

E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.pack(side = TOP)
E2 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E2.pack(side = BOTTOM)

top.bind('<Escape>', select_e1)
top.bind('<Return>', select_e2)

top.mainloop()
```

What I want is when I pressed Return key after I wrote something on E1 entry,
I want to go to E2 entry and keep typing on E2 entry, and vice versa.

It's my first writing here. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to use the focus function. This works for me.

```
from tkinter import *

def select_e1(event):
    E1.focus()


def select_e2(event):
    E2.focus()

top = Tk()
top.geometry("300x200")

E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.pack(side = TOP)
E2 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E2.pack(side = BOTTOM)

top.bind('<Escape>', select_e1)
top.bind('<Return>', select_e2)

top.mainloop()
```